# Is there anything like JSONObject.getString() to get !DOCTYPE method

Tags: php, android, json, getstring

I am POSTing to a PHP file from my website. I am not using JSON, so when I try to use code like `Log.e("errr", jsonObj.getString("err"));` I get a system.err saying:

```
07-27 20:57:29.274: W/System.err(2431): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Is there a method like `JSONObject` that I can use to parse/get the given string that I want to get?

Comment: Hmmmmm.... this doesn't make much sense. You can't parse JSON out of an XML-like input.

Comment: @dmon, i got that. but is there a method like json for xml file?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the XML, there's some methods that work better than others. You might want begin by taking a look at using  [SAXParser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).

Comment: @dmon, that doesnt look like it will look for me. I am using php with doctype. i mean i dont know much about php and this so if i am just seeing it wrong can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier just to restructure my php so that I could call json.